# java 8 - Arrays.stream().filter to filter out empty string and convert into array

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have an example as follows. I just want to convert a string delimited by ',' and convert it into a Long Array without an empty string. `productIdParams` contains `[1]`, but when I execute this, I get an exception.

> java.lang.ArrayStoreException     at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)    at
>   java.util.stream.SpinedBuffer.copyInto(SpinedBuffer.java:194)     at
>   java.util.stream.Nodes$SpinedNodeBuilder.copyInto(Nodes.java:1290)    at
>   java.util.stream.SpinedBuffer.asArray(SpinedBuffer.java:215)  at
>   java.util.stream.Nodes$SpinedNodeBuilder.asArray(Nodes.java:1296)     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:439)

```
String test = "1,";
String[] productIdParams = Iterables.toArray(com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(",").omitEmptyStrings().split(test), String.class);
try {
    Long[] productIds = Arrays.stream(productIdParams).filter(productId -> !productId.isEmpty()).toArray(Long[]::new);
        System.out.println(productIds[0]);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are expecting input to be "real" CSV, use a real CSV parser such as OpenCSV or the one in Apache Commons.

Comment: _"I get an exception"_ -- care to share the stack trace?

Comment: Why do you use `com.google.common.base.Splitter` for splitting the string. You can just do `Arrays.stream(test.split(','))...`

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to make a `Long[]` from a `String[]`, this is not allowed.
Instead, use the `map` intermediate operation to cast your `String` values to `Long` objects.

```
Arrays.stream(productIdParams)
      .filter(productId -> !productId.isEmpty())
      .map(Long::parseLong)
      .toArray(Long[]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to convert your `String` to `Long`:

```
Long[] productIds = Arrays.stream(productIdParams)
                          .filter(productId -> !productId.isEmpty())
                          .map(Long::parseLong)
                          .toArray(Long[]::new);
```

When invoke `System.arrayCopy`, the exception is thrown because underlying data has different type and size

Answer (score 1):

Keep things simple

```
String test = "1,,2,";
    String[] productIdParams = test.split(",");
    try  {
        Long[] productIds = Arrays.stream(productIdParams).filter(productId -> !productId.isEmpty()).map( Long::parseLong).toArray(Long[]::new);
        System.out.println(productIds);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Your .filter will remove empty spaces from the array and .map converts your string to map